# Show that f is Lebesgue integrable on R?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Show that $f(x)=1/x^{1/2}, x \in (0,1]$  is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Continuous functions are Riemann integrable hence Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @Chazz True but this function, being unbounded, is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: If f is bounded defined on a closed, bounded function and it's Riemann integrable then it's Lebesgue integrable over that same interval.

Answer (score 3):

The functions $f_n(x)=\frac1{x^{1/2}}\,1_{(1/n,1]}(x)$ are non-negative, bounded, and measurable. Moreover, $f_n\nearrow f$. By monotone convergence, 
$$
\int_{(0,1]}f=\lim_n\int_{(0,1]}f_n=\lim_n\int_{1/n}^1\frac{dx}{x^{1/2}}=\lim_n\,2\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)=2
$$

Comment: but this function is unbounded?????

Comment: I mean over (0,1]

Comment: The $f$ is indeed unbounded. The Lebesgue integral does not require functions to be unbounded.

Comment: That is right.
But you say f_n (x) is bounded???

Comment: Of course: for each $n$, $0\leq f_n(x)\leq \sqrt n$ for all $x$.